# Searching last committed files in git that matches to given file path

Tags: git, grep

I am getting last committed files using below git command,

```
git diff --name-only --relative= --diff-filter=AMDR --cached @~
```

Then I am getting output as below,

```
bitbucket-pipelines.yml
app-connect/source/cn/ConnectBuild.sh
```

Now I want to check "is there any files from `app-connect/source/cn/` path, then only I do some thing.

ex:

```
if git diff --name-only --relative= --diff-filter=AMDR --cached @~  | grep "/app-connect/source/cn"; then do something; fi
```

Could you please tell me how to use grep or regular expressions to check the existence of the files in the given path in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be much simpler with git show

```
lines=$( git show --pretty="" --name-only -- app-connect/source/cn | wc -l )
if [ $lines -gt 0 ]; then
    echo do something
fi
```

If you reeeeeeally need to use grep to check for the paths, do not provide the path to git, pipe into grep, set the regular expression there, then pipe into wc

```
lines=$( git show --pretty="" --name-only | egrep blahblah | wc -l )
```

Comment: As a sidenote, just in case you're unsure that the last commit is indeed on the currently checked out branch, you could consider replacing the `show --pretty=""` part and check on all branches with `git log --all -1 --no-merges --name-only --pretty=format:""`